# Adding a command to a listbox in Tk using Perl

Tags: perl, listbox, tk-toolkit

I want to have a `Listbox` that each time that an entry is chosen, it'll do something. Like the `-command` option for `Checkbutton`, that allows to run a subroutine each time the check button is pressed, in addition to changing the value of the corresponding variable.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bind to bind your subroutine to the click event should do what you want:

```
# Left mouse button loads file and eval's if .pl suffix.  See the
# OnLoad sub for more details.
$ListBox->bind('', [\&OnLoad] )
```

see [TK tutorial](http://www.hisel.com/perl/TkTutorial/)

Comment: The event you are looking for is probably `<<ListboxSelect>>`, which is issued every time a listbox's selection is changed.